# How to change a map from Super Flat to Normal; Minecraft Bukkit Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

Title says it all. Is there a way for me to change the map from a Super Flat to a normal, or even just add a few more layers of dirt/stone to the map?

I have the World Edit pluggin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `level-type` setting in server.properties to `DEFAULT`.
When you select an area in WorldEdit, use `//regen` to regenerate the area.